# how to show a bootstrap modal on a check box click event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How to show a bootstrap modal on a check box click event

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `type="check box"` did you really just typed that?

Comment: I updated,that my mistake sorry now please check

Comment: Your code is working fine in the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/1331/)

Answer (score 0):

Correct the first line from this :

```
<input type="check box" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

to this :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a click event

```
<input type="checkbox" class="openmodal">
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
 $('.openmodal').click(function(){
     $('#myModal').modal('toggle');//.modal('show')/.modal('hide');
    });
```

if you want more control use a if statement to test if its checked

```
$('.openmodal').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')) {
             $('#myModal').modal('show');
           } else {
             $('#myModal').modal('hide');
           }
        });
```

Comment: if we checked out side model then the checkbox tick is still there. how to solve this issue

Comment: to remove the check on close use `$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
 $('.openmodal').removeAttr('checked');
})`